# Why is this line of code Wrong in every Wordpress .Htaccess security article?

Tags: htaccess, security, regex

The following line of code (RegEx) is partly wrong in every Wordpress .Htaccess hardening article I've seen. Why is that?

```
<FilesMatch "^.*(error_log|wp-config\.php|php.ini|\.[hH][tT][aApP].*)$">
order deny,allow
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The **"."** in the **"php.ini"** selector (in the first line) should be escaped with a **"\"** and should look like this **"php\.ini"** in order to **only** match the **php.ini** file.

Instead, in it's current form the **"."** in the code above will match any character between **"php"** and **"ini"**, matching URLs like **"/phpaini"** or **"/phpmini"**.

While this technically still works because it **also** matches the php.ini file, I can't help but wonder why the **"."** isn't escaped.

Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps it's just a typo, so you could comment on the article or contact the author to let them fix the issue.

Comment: @SallyCJ Although the OP is claiming that this is in **every** related article they've seen.

Comment: Yes @MrWhite, I noticed that at first glance. I was just mainly saying it's probably a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is partly wrong **in every Wordpress .Htaccess hardening article** I've seen.

Unfortunately it is very common for Apache config/regex code snippets to be blindly copy/pasted and errors do propagate. Unless there is some obscure vulnerability we are not aware of then I would bet that that is what has happened here. (Although matching "too much" is not necessarily a problem here.)

Although per-directory `php.ini` files (in the public HTML space) is not a common scenario these days, so this check is arguably bogus anyway. However, `.user.ini` files are, so this should probably be added (ie. `\.user\.ini`).

And `error_log`, `php.ini` and `.htaccess` / `.htpasswd` files are not specific to WordPress.

However, there are other potential "errors" with the code snippet:

- The `^.*` prefix on the regex is entirely superfluous and just makes the regex a little less efficient. However, the effect of this is that the remainder of the regex is essentially just a suffix. In other words, it will match `<anything>error_log`, `<anything>wp-config.php`, `<anything>php<anychar>ini` and `<anything>.[hH][tT][aApP]<anything>`. Which is probably unnecessary.
- The directives `Order` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4, which is more likely what you are using these days.  These directives have been moved to an optional extension (mod_access_compat) which might not even be installed. On Apache 2.4 you should be using the equivalent `Require` directive instead:

  ```
  Require all denied
  ```

  But note that you should not mix old and new auth directives in the same config as you can get unexpected results due to the order in which these directives are processed.